# Calling external class functions from within ENUM functions

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I've been having some irregular issues with **ENUMS** lately and was wondering if it is safe/allowed for functions from external classes to be called as values within ENUM functions *(not the raw values).* Here's an example:

```
enum pageData: Int {
    case page1
    case page2
    case page3

    static let pageGroup = [page1, page2, page3]

    func initPage(caption: String = "") -> myCustomType {
      var mctData: myCustomType!

      switch self {
        case .page1:
          let text = (caption.isEmpty) ? extClass.getCaptionFunc("page1") : caption
          mctData = myCustomType(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/01"))
        case .page2:
          let text = (caption.isEmpty) ? extClass.getCaptionFunc("page2") : caption
          mctData = myCustomType(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/03"))
        default: ()
      }

    return mctData  
  }
}
```

There are two separate example functions *(extClass.getCaptionFunc() & extClass.formatDateFunc())* being called in the **SWITCH cases** within the **ENUM** to populate the required data that would be returned by the **ENUM** function *initPage()*.

**Q: Is this a safe/allowable design?** Tests so far are inconclusive, where the app crashes when the enumerations and switch cases get too large, but works fine on smaller footprints.

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: What is this call: mctData = pageData(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/03"))? Is this an init in an extension?

Comment: No; it's just a STRUCT *init()* being populated according to the selected page. ***Sorry; a typo there!*** CORRECTED

Comment: THAT makes more sense. Ok. It doesn't smell right to me: I'd prefer to see the enum type at the bottom of the food chain rather than call out to other classes. If you refactor initPage() to be within the extClass - passing in the pageData enum as an argument - does it look better?

Comment: I think I understand. So, no *initPage()* function in the **ENUM** itself, but rather, move the *initPage()* function into the **extClass** class. Won't I be losing the **self** enumeration in this approach?

Comment: What's with the ***EMPHASIS*** on enum?

Comment: you should use the enum, to give you the right string for your extClass. So give rhe enum a variable that returns page1 or page2 for the self value and use it where you need this variable. You call the initPage somewhere with page.initPage ... here u already have the enum and can get the string that you need when you dont have a caption

Comment: @iSofia You can still switch on the enum value. e.g. func initPage(page: pageData, caption: String = "")/switch page. I'm not sure what the point is of extClass.getCaptionFunc, but if you're just passing in a string equal to the enum name then you can pass in the enum itself instead. You do realise that enum values can be used outside of the enum itself?

Comment: i agree with @ces

Comment: @ces You're right. The ENUM is a little heavy. I'll try to refactor by splitting up the code. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @BjörnRo I have no need for the raw string values; only the integers; the function returns a longer descriptive string, and not just *page1, page2, etc.* Moreover, it is important that I be able to address the enumerations by name, for both raw value and function; *eg:* `page2.initPage()` but called within an iterator, like `for page in pageData.pageGroup { someDict[x] = page.initPage(...) }` Thank you for your suggestions; I'll need them when refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is it safe?

While this code looks like it works in most cases, there is definitely opportunity for some improvement.

If this were a code review, I'd say the use of the implicitly unwrapped `myCustomType!` is a dangerous choice. Your function needs to return a `myCustomType`, so it should really do so in every case, and the implicitly-unwrapped variable is going to do more harm than good.

Also along those lines, I see no need to have a `default` case here. Let swift do its exhaustiveness-checking, so that you know when you forget to implement a case. Using `default` undermines that. With what you have written, calling `pageData.page3.initPage()` will crash the program because there is no case for `.page3` so the implicitly-unwrapped `mctData` will be nil.

If you absolutely need to just "shut up" the compiler, you can provide `fatalError()` as the implementation of any case that you can't actually implement yet. That would be preferable in my book.

About the static function: while there's no technical issue with doing that, it would not be my go-to solution. It's hard to say for sure, because I don't know what that code does, but I would probably start with that implementation inside the `pageData` class as a computed property, for example:

```
var defaultCaption: String {
    switch self {
    case .page1: // something, something "page1"
    // etc. for the rest of the cases
    }
}
```

Finally, the fact that all the class and constant names are not title-cased (like `PageData,`MyCustomType`) makes the code you gave here very unusual and somewhat harder to read. I would suggest taking a look through the language [API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) if you haven't already. Following community standards will make your code easier to follow for those not already familiar with it. Including folks on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: You're absolutely correct; **it was the implicitly unwrapped variable that was causing the crashes.** Thank you for that, and for the comprehensive review. I'm not familiar with **fatalError()** but I'll surely look into it now. As far as the naming conventions go, I had read about the preference for capitalization for type names, but bad force of habit that I'll need to change. Thanks a whole lot, mklbtz.

Comment: Happy to help; thank you for the kind words. What language are you coming from? Just curious. @iSofia

Comment: C# and Java. But amateur hour all the way! :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'safe'? Your code contains the incorrect syntax.
Don't use force unwrapped values `myCustomType!`.

1. Use correct case > String value mapping by `:String`
2. Use correct code syntax for `pageGroup`
3. Use full switch

> ```
> enum pageData: String {
>     case page1
>     case page2
>     case page3
> static let pageGroup: pageData = [.page1, .page2, .page3]
>
>     func initPage(caption: String = "") -> myCustomType {
>       var mctData: myCustomType
>
>       switch self {
>         case .page1:
>           let text = caption.isEmpty ? extClass.getCaptionFunc(rawValue) : caption
>           mctData = myCustomType(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/01"))
>         case .page2:
>           let text = caption.isEmpty ? extClass.getCaptionFunc(rawValue) : caption
>           mctData = myCustomType(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/03"))
>         case .page3:
> let text = caption.isEmpty ? extClass.getCaptionFunc(rawValue) : caption
>           mctData = myCustomType(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/01"))
>       }
>
>     return mctData  
>   }
> }
> ```

what about your question? There is no difference between such methods and computed variables in your case. `extClass.getCaptionFunc` is ok.

Comment: It was the unwrapped variable that was causing all this ruckus! Nevertheless, I'll refactor my code based on your suggestions. Thank you. BTW, I've always been using the enumerator names without the dot notation in front **(.page1)** and it works. But it also seems to work with the dot. Is there any significance to it?

Comment: @iSofia without dot it looks like a variable

Comment: @iSofia the compilator confuses when see page1 without dot

Comment: The dot notation seems to have a small irregularity. It raises an `ambiguous without more context` error if **all the cases** in the array contains the dot. But there's no error if the last one is left without the dot. `static let pageGroup = [.page1, .page2, .page3] //error` -- `static let pageGroup = [.page1, .page2, page3] //no error` *Strange.*

Comment: @iSofia typo. Correct : `let pageGroup: pageData = [.page1, .page2, .page3]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggested refactoring based on the comments above. If there's some fixed relationship between the enum value and the caption returned by getCaptionFunc or the date from formatDateFunc then you can consider whether those functions should be implemented within the enum, but without knowing your intent I can't be sure (e.g. if page1 should always be titled "Page 1" unless overridden, then consider giving the enum a string property equal to that via a switch self). And if that's true, then maybe the extClass.initPage is entirely unnecessary, and you can give myCustomType a constructor that takes an enum parameter.

```
enum pageData: Int {
  case page1
  case page2
  case page3

  static let pageGroup = [page1, page2, page3]
}

class extClass
{
  func initPage(page: pageData, caption: String = "") -> myCustomType {
    let text = caption.isEmpty ? getCaptionFunc(page) : caption 
    return myCustomType(param1: text, param2: extClass.formatDateFunc("2018/12/01"))
  }

  func getCaptionFunc(page: pageData) -> String {       
    switch page {
    case .page1:
      return "Page 1 Caption"
    case .page2:
      return "Page 2 Caption"
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Very much cleaner. I'll try and see if I'm able to implement it in my current code. Thanks again, ces.